# No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key

Tags: macos, startup, macbook-pro

When I boot my Macbook Pro 13" Retina (running newest Mavericks), it is showing me this error:
[image]

However! If I boot holding the <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>-key, it shows Mavericks as option. When I  press <kbd>⌤ enter</kbd>-key to confirm, it will boot normally. (I'm using this Macbook now to type this question).

Why won't my Macbook boot anymore? I did not use disk utility or something. What can cause this issue?

Comment: Do you run Windows on the Machine ?. Try following : Startup by pressing the X key, to force Mac OS X startup, or Startup by pressing the keys cmd-alt-shift-delete, so the system will boot to the Macintosh HD.

Comment: No, I don't have installed bootcamp or Windows.

Comment: I did have windows installed and the answer by @grg saved me. Thank you both! Now just please accept an answer OP

Answer (score 3):

Boot normally then open **System Preferences.app** > **Startup Disk**. Select your drive and reboot. This should [bless the drive](http://help.bombich.com/kb/troubleshooting/what-makes-a-volume-bootable) and make it the default when powering on.

Answer (score 1):

Boot whilst holding ⌥ to open the boot selector, then instead of just pressing Enter on the Mavericks partition, hold ⌃ (control) as you press Enter and the ↑ arrow should change into a circular arrow indicating that this will be the default partition.

Answer (score 0):

Better than that. I today tried this manipulation when I got the same error message : on startup keep pressing COMMAND + ALT + P + R to reset the NVRAM of your mac. Let the system restart 2 or 3 times (you know with the famous "Bammm" Mac sound). This should sort things out :)